# Hosting a bundle of scripts inside of NuxtJS

Tags: javascript, apache, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I'm a Systems Admin with limited-to-moderate programming experience. I got roped into creating a front-end app for work using Nuxt and Apache (Apache and SSR is a requirement). One of the other requirements in that I need to host this folder of JS scripts at `/login`. The scripts have nothing to do with Nuxt itself. I just need to host them as static assets for Apache to work with.

I've tried putting the folder within the static directory, but that didn't do anything. I've also tried messing around with webpack and vue-loader to no avail. Right now I have a temporary fix where I have Apache serving the login folder along with a redirect to the NodeJS server. However, I feel like this is messy.

Has anyone else dealt with this?

Comment: The `static` directory would be the right place for that. What do you mean by `didn't do anything`? How did you try to access the scripts after putting them under `static`?

Comment: I put the directory containing the static site in the `static` folder. Then I tried to navigate to `http://localhost:3000/{directory name}`. Now that I'm thinking about it, I might need to set up a route or something.